# can't seem to access to $wpdb after calling a php function to display my posts via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

hi I wanted to have a list that displays archives of posts group by year
when users click on the years, the posts will be displayed

I am using ajax to call a functions.php, and within there's a function
will grab the posts, but I can't seem to access the $wpdb ?

Thanks a lot!

html:

```
<ul id="years">
<?php
$months = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR( post_date ) AS year,post_title as     title, ID as post_id, COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status =     'publish' and post_date <= now( ) and post_type = 'post' GROUP BY year ORDER BY post_date   DESC");
foreach($months as $month) : ?>
<li>
<a href="" onClick="year_to_post_titles(<?php echo $month->year; ?>)">
<?php if(in_category("photography",$month->post_id)){
echo $month->year;
} ?>
</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

ajax:

```
<script>

function year_to_post_titles(year){
var find_titles="find_titles";
//request ajax
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
//state change
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&& xmlhttp.status==200){
document.getElementById("work_items").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php bloginfo(template_directory) ?>/functions.php?func=find_titles&y="+year,true);
xmlhttp.send()
}

</script>
```

functions.php:

```
 <?php
$which_func=$_GET["func"];
if(function_exists($which_func)){
    find_titles();
};

function find_titles(){
global $wpdb;
$which_year=$_GET["y"];
$titles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR( post_date ) AS year,post_title as title, ID as post_id, COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( ) and post_type = 'post' GROUP BY year ORDER BY post_date DESC");
foreach($titles as $var_title){
echo "<li><a href=''>";
if(in_category("photography",$var_title->post_id)){
    echo $var_title->title;
    } 
echo "</a></li>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `functions.php` via AJAX, the file does not have a global variable called `$wpdb`. That's no wonder, because normally `functions.php` does not care about this. Instead you should register [an AJAX PHP callback function within wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Then `$wpdb` is available.

Comment: by the way why is $wpdb isn't available within functions.php
isn't itself part of the wordpress as well ?

Comment: Not if you call it directly (via AJAX).

Comment: thanks man any other links or reading you suggested about this you recommend ?

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, you shouldn't do this :

```
<?php
$which_func=$_GET["func"];
if(function_exists($which_func)){
    $which_func();
};
?>
```

If you do it, an user will be able to call any existing functions (like phpinfo() for exemple, but it could be worst with a little bit of imagination). It's a huge security breach.